# Cannot get key handler to compile in Rust - GTK program

Tags: rust, gtk, glib

I'm afraid this might be a silly error, but I don't see it. The following code:

```
let key_handler = gtk::EventControllerKey::new();
controller.obj().add_controller(&key_handler);
key_handler.connect_key_pressed(clone!(@weak controller => move |_ctlr, key, _code, state| {
    controller.keyboard_input(key, state);
    gtk::Inhibit(false)
}));
```

does not compile. It gets the error:

```
error[E0069]: `return;` in a function whose return type is not `()`
  --> src/controller/imp.rs:80:45
   |
80 |               key_handler.connect_key_pressed(clone!(@weak controller => move |_ctlr, key, _code, state| {
   |  _____________________________________________^
81 | |                 controller.keyboard_input(key, state);
82 | |                 gtk::Inhibit(false)
83 | |             }
84 | |             )
   | |_____________^ return type is not `()`
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `clone` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0069`.
```

I think the problem is in the `clone!` expansion, but I'm not sure. Am I missing some simple way to fix this, or is this not the right way to use clone? Right above it I have

```
controller.start_buttonx.connect_clicked(clone!(@weak controller => move |xx| BOARDS[1].emit_by_name::<()>("test-signal", &[&x])));
```

which looks awfully similar, and that has no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and there are a lot of dependencies here, so I'm not going to attempt to reproduce your error, but I'll take a guess.

Rust error messages are usually really good, so you should read them carefully and try to understand what they mean.

> `return;` in a function whose return type is not `()`
>
> = note: this error originates in the macro `clone`

This tells me that the `clone!` macro is returning a function or closure, which contains a line like this:

```
return;
```

This is okay, but only works if the return type of the function is `()`. The input to `clone!` contains a closure, so I'm guessing that this combined into the generated closure somehow. But your closure returns `Inhibit` which, [according to the GTK docs](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/stable/0.14/docs/gtk/struct.Inhibit.html), is a struct.

This is causing the type-checker to think that the return type of the closure is `Inhibit`, since there presumably aren't type annotations in the macro. This conflicts with the `return;` statement added by the macro itself.

You can probably fix this by adding a semicolon:

```
gtk::Inhibit(false);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm sorry for providing such inadequate a
description, I had looked at this for so long I guess I expected everyone would recognize the return issue.

I think the problem is that the closure needs to return the
gtk::Inhibit, and it is not getting past the clone! call. I'm
reasonably sure it is supposed to work - passing copies of
variables through to the closure is the whole point of the clone!()
macro. I was hoping to find out what I was doing wrong.

Your suggestions got me thinking again in more depth about my
problem, thanks for helping out a stuck newbie.

Comment: You can also try `cargo expand` to see what the fully expanded macro looks like.